# Create custom log format in RubyMine

Tags: regex, ruby, logging, regex-lookarounds, rubymine

In my Ruby program, I use [logger](https://github.com/ruby/logger) to export log to file.
But when I open .log file in Rubymine, it show 'log format not recognized'
[image]

My log file content is :

```
E, [2019-05-09T11:29:09.915477 #23628] ERROR -- : quang.log: No time
E, [2019-05-09T11:29:09.915712 #23628] ERROR -- : quang.log: /home/quang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:109:in `sleep'
/home/quang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:109:in `wait'
/home/quang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:109:in `wait'
/home/quang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra/future.rb:622:in `block in get'
/home/quang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
```

I tried to add new log format like this:

```
^([\w]+),\s+\[([^\]\s]+)\s+#([^\]]+)]\s+(\w+)\s+--\s+(\w+)?:\s+(.+)$
```

[image]

It does match with :

```
E, [2019-05-09T11:29:09.915477 #23628] ERROR -- : quang.log: No time
```

But notification above doesn't disappear.

How do I fix this?

Comment: @Emma I tried before but it not work. The default regex pattern also use those 2 chars. See the screen shot : https://imgur.com/UMrJ0gz

Comment: Try `^(\w+),\s+\[([^\]\s]+)\s+#(\d+)]\s+(\w+)\s+--\s+(\w+)?:\s+(.+(?:\R(?!\w+,\s+\[[^\]\s]+\s+#\d+).*)*)$`,  see https://regex101.com/r/rtgv26/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't work. Have you tried it in RubyMine 2019?